# Set up both access point and client on an offline Pi

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-zero-w

I'd like to set up a Pi Zero as both a WiFi client and an access point using the built-in WiFi module. Most tutorials I see assume that the Pi has internet connectivity, but I want to set mine up to be offline. Specifically, when a WiFi connection is available, the Pi should connect to it. At the same time, it should act as an access point that I can connect to and SSH into the Pi, or view some content served by a web server on the Pi on the local LAN it creates, all offline.

How would I go about tuning wpa_supplicant, hostapd, and the network interfaces to achieve this?

Comment: Odd question. But you could use this instead:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview

Comment: I did an extensive write-up on this here: https://blog.thewalr.us/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/ Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial sounds like it might meet your WiFi setup requirements:
 http://imti.co/post/145442415333/raspberry-pi-3-wifi-station-ap

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers might be deleted.